# Obscure way to test for own properties

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

In the book Javascript: the definitive Guide Sixth Edition by David Flanagan page 147, the author discusses a caveat when iterating through an array with a for..in loop, the following is a quote (bold is mine)

> ...For this reason you should not use a for/in loop on an array unless
>   you include an additional test to filter out unwanted properties.
>   **You might use either of these tests**:
>
> ```
> for(var i in a) {
>    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue; // Skip inherited properties
>    // loop body here
> }
>
> for(var i in a) {
>    // Skip i if it is not a non-negative integer
>    if (String(Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(i)))) !== i) continue;
> }
> ```

Now the first code snippet is clear to me, inherited properties will be skipped.

However, the second code snippet is not clear to me at all.

To my understanding, the second code snippet will skip over *any non-numeric property* of the array (whether it is an own property or not (unlike the first code snippet))

but if that's the case couldn't you just use a simplified test like:

```
if (Number(i) != i) continue;
```

So why is the author using such a complicated expression?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Acctually, it will skip all non-negative numbers as comment says. (E.g. -5 will be skipped). Not just non-numeric values.

Comment: the 2nd one would hit prototype-inherited numerical properties (if someone did that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, here are some examples that will fail:

### Floating point number:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a['1.5'] = 'busted';
for(var i in a) {
    if (Number(i) != i) continue;
    document.getElementById('output1').textContent += i + '\n';
}
for(var i in a) {
    if (String(Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(i)))) !== i) continue;
    document.getElementById('output2').textContent += i + '\n';
}
```

```html
<h3>Number(i) != i</h3>
<pre id="output1"></pre>
<h3>String(Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(i)))) !== i</h3>
<pre id="output2"></pre>
```

### Negative numbers:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a['-5'] = 'busted';
for(var i in a) {
    if (Number(i) != i) continue;
    document.getElementById('output1').textContent += i + '\n';
}
for(var i in a) {
    if (String(Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(i)))) !== i) continue;
    document.getElementById('output2').textContent += i + '\n';
}
```

```html
<h3>Number(i) != i</h3>
<pre id="output1"></pre>
<h3>String(Math.floor(Math.abs(Number(i)))) !== i</h3>
<pre id="output2"></pre>
```

This is what the `Math.abs` and `Math.floor` calls are guarding against.

BTW, there really is no advantage to using a for in loop for array indexes. I would recommend using an index-based loop.

Comment: Are the Number and String conversions and strict equals necessary? ie wouldn't the following do the same thing? `Math.floor(Math.abs(i))) != i`

Comment: @Danield I think you would be alright using non-strict equality in this case. Personally, I try to avoid non-strict equality, as do many developers.

Comment: Is there a special level of hell for those who use negative floating point numbers as property names?

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Probably. Along with people who talk at theaters and deep-fried Twinkies.